# How to replace a tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The documentation for [`chrome.tabs.onReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onReplaced) event states

> Fired when a tab is replaced with another tab due to prerendering or
> instant.

What does it mean, how to "replace" a tab to test the event?